# "So that he will do" (future tense) or "so that he does" (present tense)

Tags: meaning, tense, present-tense, future-constructions

> You must be sure to tell him this so that he **will do** it.

> You must be sure to tell him this so that he **does** it.

Do these two sentences mean same?
I am getting problem use of tenses after so that or adverb of purpose. In first sentence, it shows clear future intention. However, using present simple tense into second sentence also shows future intention.
What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant difference in meaning here. Future actions are often described using the simple present. for example:

> - You tell him what to do, and then he does it.
> - Tomorrow ahw leave school at three and goes to the concert.
> - He flies to the Coast on Friday.
> - You give him the problem, and he solves it.

The difference is a matter of style and emphasis. Form using the auxiliary "will" emphasize the future nature of the event.

Answer (score 0):

If  you want him to do it, **does** is best.

**So he will** do it can be iffy. It gives him the possibility of doing it at some point.