# so that + Present / Future

Tags: difference, present-tense, future-constructions

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/so-that-will-would-present-simple.3867629/):
**(1a)** *I’ll post the CD today so that you **get** it by the weekend*.
**(1b)** *I’ll post the CD today so that you **will get** it by the weekend*.

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/so-that-subjunctive.3095339/post-17949522):
**(2a)** *How do I transform a sentence so that it **begins** with "I wish"*?
my version:
**(2b)** *How do I transform a sentence so that it **will begin** with "I wish"*?

[stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58636/312479):
**(3a)** *I want you to give this money to him so that he **has** enough for lunch*.
my version:
**(3b)** *I want you to give this money to him so that he **will have** enough for lunch*.

---

What is the difference between a- and b-variants?

Will I better understand this difference, if I analyze all possible meanings of "so that" in these sentences?
Am I right that?:
In (1a), (1b) and (3b) "so that" can have only two meanings: "in order that" and "with the result that".
In (2a), (2b) and (3a) "so that" can have only one meaning: "in order that".

---

P.S.: I saw a similar question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326765/so-that-plus-future-or-present-tenses), but I didn't quite understand that example and also the explanation there didn't seem to me enough to cover the topic.